# Flutter: Page disposed but http request no destroy/cancel

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently using [http 0.12.2](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package. When I disposed current page the http request still ongoing and didn't stop the request.

Any idea how to stop all request activity when the page already disposed ? Thanks.

Comment: Some code would help. I assume you're using Futures (async await) this won't stop the request. What you can do is to use streams and dispose the stream subscription that will cancel the execution of the code. Even so, if the request is sent, the server might get it either way but you won't get the response in return.

Comment: I think it is not possible. Once the request is made. It is gone to the server and there is no way we can cancel it. We may be able to discard the result received, but the execution will happen on the server side.

Comment: Ok thanks danypata & VilsadPP for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter usually only complains if you attempt to change some state within the widget after it has been disposed of. You could use the `mounted` state in order to determine if the widget is mounted before running mutating code.

For example:

```
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  
  http.get(Uri.https('www.googleapis.com', '/books/v1/volumes', {'q': '{http}'})).then((_) {
    // This is when dart usually complains if the widget is disposed,
    // so let's check if we are 'mounted' first.
    if (mounted) {
      // Do some mutation
    }
  });
}
```

Here is the [documentation for mounted](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/mounted.html).